# Getting layout (Resource) from view object

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Let's say I have a view object:

```
View elem = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.element_activity, null);
```

I do some editing to this view dynamically and need to pass it as an argument to a function that takes a resource (ex. R.layout.element_activity). Is it possible to pass this edited view into that function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check is java pass by value or pass by reference..

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to pass this edited view into that function?

No, there is no overloaded version of `inflate` method in [`LayoutInflater`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) class, which accepts the `View` as parameter.

```
View    inflateinflate(int resource, ViewGroup root)
View    inflate(XmlPullParser parser, ViewGroup root)
View    inflate(XmlPullParser parser, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)
View    inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)
```

**Note:** if you have the view instance then simply use it, no need to inflate new view from resources or anything

Comment: Okay thanks, so its there another way to do this? Essentially what I'm trying to do is edit a view and then get the resource id from it so I can pass it into the tab view library I'm using.

Comment: it's quite unclear what exactly you trying to achieve, resource ids are fix, you can simply pass them though i suspect that your function wants to add more views into a constructed view so if that's the case then you can create views and add them using `addView` method